# Why does this statement hold for positive semidefinite matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

I would like to understand why if $P$ is positive semidefinite, then $x^{\text{T}}Px=0$ if and only if $Px=0$. How can I prove this? 
I can say that $x'Px=x'M'Mx$, where $M$ is the square root of $P$, then the norm $Mx=0$. How can I arrive to $Px=0$? And how to understand with intuition this?

Thanks.

Extra: If the matrix was positive definite, would it be the same?

Comment: What you are calling x' is the transpose of x?

Comment: Yes, it is the transpose

Comment: Since $Mx=0$, we also get $Px=M^2x=0$.

Comment: If P is positive definite then $x^tPx > 0$ for all x, so it can never be 0

Comment: @user622002 slight correction.. all nonzero $x$ :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I’m assuming that we’re talking about finite vector spaces over the real numbers)

If P is diagonal, then the result is clear:

If P = $\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1} & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & a_{2} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
  &  & \ddots & &   \\
0 & \cdots &0&  a_{k} & \cdots\\
&&\ddots\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$ with $a_i > 0$, then if
$x = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ \cdots \\ x_n \end{pmatrix}$ we have: $x^tPx = a_1x_1^2 + \cdots +a_kx_k^2 = 0$ implies that $x_1 = x_2 = \cdots = x_k = 0$, since all of the $a_i$ are strictly positive. And in this case it is clear that $x \in ker(P)$.

If P is not diagonal, then it must be congruent to a diagonal matrix like the one considered in the first case, say $P = M^t D M$ where $M \in GL_n(\Bbb{R})$ and $D$ is a positive semidefinite diagonal matrix.
Thus we have $x^t P x = (Mx)^t D (Mx)$, and hence $x^tPx = 0 \implies Mx \in ker(D) $ by the previous case.
But $D= (M^t)^{-1}P(M)^{-1}$ so we get that $ 0=D(Mx) = (M^t)^{-1}Px \implies Px = 0$ because $(M^t)^{-1}$ is invertibile.

EDIT: the theorem I implicitly used to say that P is congruent to a diagonal matrix is Sylverster’s Theorem

EDIT2: P is an n by n matrix

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Note however that your motivation is given for positive definite matrices (all $a_i>0$) and not positive semi-definite. Does it will change ?

Comment: I’m sorry but maybe the illustration wasn’t clear. Not all of the entries on the diagonal are >0, only the first k, where k is less than it equal to n. This can always be assumed since you can just change the order of the entries on the diagonal freely by changing basis adequately.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I did not see that was a $n$x$n$ matrix. Now I get it.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $x^TPx=0$. As $P$ is positive semidefinite, $0\le(Px-tx)^TP(Px-tx)=x^TP^3x-2t\|Px\|^2$ for every $t\in\mathbb R$. Hence $Px$ must be zero.

As all positive definite matrices are positive semidefinite, the above argument is still valid when $P$ is positive definite. However, in this case, there is an easier argument: by the definition of positive definiteness, if $x^TPx=0$, we must have $x=0$. Hence $Px=0$.

If you want to use square roots instead, you may use the (unique) positive semidefinite square root $P^{1/2}$ of $P$ and argue as follows: if $x^TPx=0$, then $\|P^{1/2}x\|^2=(P^{1/2}x)^T(P^{1/2}x)=x^TPx=0$. Hence $P^{1/2}x=0$ and $Px=P^{1/2}P^{1/2}x=0$.

Comment: @Hanno Thanks for catching that. It's fixed now.

Comment: Pleasure $\,\ddot\smile\,$ after previous upvote.

Comment: @user1551 Thank you, the motivation with square root is clear. Why you argue that $x^TPx=x^TP^3x=0$?

Comment: @user1551 I lost the term $+x^TPx$. Anyway you are saying that $x^TP^3x - 2t\|Px\|=0$ (why this imply $Px=0$?), so $x^TPx=x^TP^3x=0$.

Comment: @user1551 I thought you demonstrated the $Px=0$ fact, by make the 3 terms equal to $0$ and exploiting the fact that $x^TPx=0$. Then, still I don't get it.. could you please explain why $x^TP^3x - 2t\|Px\|>=0$ implies $Px=0$?

Comment: @Alberto If $Px\ne0$, its norm will be positive. Therefore $x^TP^3x-2t\|Px\|^2$ is negative when $t>0$ is sufficiently large. Geometrically, $y=x^TP^3x-2t\|Px\|^2$ is a straight line with slope $\|Px\|^2$ on the $ty$-plane. If the slope is nonzero, the line must enter the lower half plane for some $t$ and make $y$ negative.

Comment: @user1551, right. And why then $x^TP^3x>=0$?

Comment: @Alberto Whether $x^TP^3x$ is $\ge0$ is irrelevant (although it is indeed $\ge0$, because $P$ is positive semidefinite). What matters is that $-2t\|Px\|^2$ can be an arbitrarily large negative number if $Px\ne0$.

Comment: @user1551 I get it. Why if $P$ is positive semi-definite then $x^TP^3x>=0$?

Comment: @Alberto $v^TPv\ge0$ for every $v$. In particular, this is true for $v=Px$.

Comment: @user1551 thank you so much. I lack some basics concept and I am trying to exercising on it.